# How to properly run a dialog from Python3/PyGObject that was generated using Glade

Tags: python-3.x, dialog, window, pygtk, pygobject

I'm having trouble running a dialog window from Python3/PyGObject that I made using Glade interface designer. The signals are not connected properly since I get this error when I try to run this script:

> AttributeError: Handler button_click_dialog not found

Also, I don't know where I can set my transient parent window:

> Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is
>   discouraged.

Here is my glade file:
http://pastebin.com/yKz3P58s

And here is my Python3/PyGObject file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Gtk imports
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

# Initialize Gtk builder and import UI
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("windowtest.glade")

# Get objects from builder
window = builder.get_object("ButtonWindow")
dialog = builder.get_object("ButtonDialog")

class ButtonWindow:

  def on_delete_window(self, *args):
    Gtk.main_quit(*args)

  def button_click_window(self, widget):
    print("button_click_window")
    response = dialog.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
      print("OK")
    elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
      print("CANCEL")
    dialog.destroy()


class ButtonDialog:

  def __init__(self):
    print("dialog init")

  def button_click_dialog(self, widget):
    print("button_click_dialog")


# Connect signals
builder.connect_signals(ButtonWindow())
builder.connect_signals(ButtonDialog())

# Show main window
window.show_all()

# Enter main loop
Gtk.main()
```

Can someone help me understand how to call/run/destroy my dialog? And how should I connect the signals?

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: Handler button_click_dialog not found

The problem is that you are connecting two classes to the same builder object here:

```
builder.connect_signals(ButtonWindow())
builder.connect_signals(ButtonDialog())
```

So you can either move the `button_click_dialog` function into the `ButtonWindow` class or you save your dialog in a separate file.

---

> Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

You can call `set_transient_for` for example when the button is clicked

```
def button_click_window(self, widget):
    print("button_click_window")
    dialog.set_transient_for(window)
    response = dialog.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        print("OK")
    elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
        print("CANCEL")
    dialog.destroy()
```

It might also make sense to switch from `dialog.destroy()` to `dialog.hide()` in case you want to be able to call the dialog several times and not just once.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, elya5. I would be very interested in separating these two to their own files. The problem is, I tried it as you explained it but I did not get it right. Can you help me to fix this?

windowwindow.py: http://pastebin.com/MW8dRLys
windowdialog.py: http://pastebin.com/1nCAUSjc
windowtest.glade: unchanged.

Comment: Put the window and the dialog in two separate glade files

Comment: Ok. How do I import, instantiate and run a dialog now that my dialog is in a separate file? I have the same .py-files as before.